# Why are moderators allowed to be impolite?

Tags: discussion, moderation

**NOTE**: I will not name any names, and this mod does not have to come forward. In fact, I'd rather they didn't they've already ruined my day and the last thing I want to do is interact with them.

I asked a question (It got deleted), and I was astonished by the pure rudeness of the moderator. I included a photo of the food in question, and it just happened to look like the dish from a stock photo, which is totally not my fault. I linked the question to an article that explained the food culture of the place where the dish I was attempting to make. The moderator said and I quote "Your link is useless at best." They continued "You plagiarized." There is no definite proof I did any of this. If you want to see where exactly I linked to, it's [this,](https://micronations.wiki/wiki/Food_culture_in_macawainia) a brief rundown of the food culture in the U.D.O.M (a micronation). But calling the link useless (and insulting the Macawainian people in doing so) and flying into an accusation like that is, in my opinion, unacceptable.

Comment: As a moderator elsewhere - and someone who's been a long time user of the site - might I suggest you change your title to something more polite?

Comment: Also how *does* one insult a fictional nation?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yeah come to think of it....

Comment: I'd assume a micronation is a country that hasn't tried yet.

Comment: If it isn't trying - how does it have a food culture? I feel like least from what I see it might not really be a great question here. Also  since the image in question *is* a stock photo - which means there's an inaccuracy, if not an outright falsehood in your post here. Which also leads me to wonder *how* the link is in any way useful

Comment: @JourneymanGeek They have a very weird culture, considering there's only 50 residents of the entire place.

Comment: and keep in mind we're talking about a nation whose national anthem literally predicted the country's collapse.

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the moderators who *didn't* interact with your original question.

Your question here on meta is, generously, misleading about the facts of the situation. It wasn't even a moderator who pointed out that the photo included in your question was identical to a portion of a stock photo, and your photo didn't just "look like" the stock photo, it was identical.

Here they are, cropped to the same region:

[image] [image]

If you're not being honest about where you got the photo from - and thus not being honest about the main subject of your question - then you're not being respectful of the time and effort of the members of the community who you're asking to answer your question.

Given this, the moderator who took action, and took the time to explain *why* they were taking that action, was acting appropriately in their role as a moderator. (I'm not going to try to go through every point in this meta question; the photo sufficiently addresses the core issue.)

Comment: alright, alright. I get it. But still, calling the link "useless at best" is a little much in my opinion. I don't have the greatest track record with the moderation, and I do respect them, but sometimes I see things they do and think "that's not right". I apologize for any inconvenience that my original question or this one may have caused.

Comment: Calling a link "useless at best" is not impolite. Links don't have feelings; they can't be insulted. That's simply a moderator assessing the quality and relevance of content, which is *exactly what moderators do*.

Comment: Saying a link is useless means the *link* is useless, i.e. linking does not add to the question. It does not mean that the content of the linked page is useless. And if we're to the point of debating about the exact best clearest way to say that, I think we're pretty far from any significant claims of moderators being rude.